# Combine: Problem when replace addObserver with Notification publisher

Tags: combine

i try to replace the addObserver method with Notification publisher
But i cant make it work , hope someone can help

i try to setup the publisher under viewDidLoad and receive notification from another swiftui . Since i cant make it work ,So I make it under viewWillAppear within the same swift file for debugging . In the below coding , I can only receive it from the old school method and the method from viewWillAppear not from the viewDidLoad . The setup in viewDidLoad not working and if i miss out let temp2 = under viewWillAppear , it didnt work too . Is that a bugs for combine?

Result is 
BBBB
CCCC

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .dismissSwiftUI, object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
        print("BBBB")
    }
    let abc = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .dismissSwiftUI).sink { (_) in
        print("AAAA")
    }
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    //        self.checkIfProfitSetup()
    let temp2 = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .dismissSwiftUI, object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
        print("CCCC")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .dismissSwiftUI ,object: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `.sink` operator](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/3362666-sink) returns an `AnyCancellable`. So your `abc` property is an `AnyCancellable`.

[The `AnyCancellable` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/anycancellable) says

> An `AnyCancellable` instance automatically calls `cancel()` when deinitialized.

Since `abc` is a local property, it is deinitialized when `viewDidLoad` returns. So your subscription is cancelled when `viewDidLoad` returns.

You need to store the `AnyCancellable` in an instance property so that it survives. `Cancellable` defines [a `store` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/cancellable/3343581-store) that helps.

I usually call them “tickets” in my code, because “cancellable” is too verbose. Thus:

```
private var tickets: [AnyCancellable] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .dismissSwiftUI, object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
        print("BBBB")
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .dismissSwiftUI)
        .sink { _ in print("AAAA") }
        .store(in: &tickets)
}
```